# Highcharts Angular with API data

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using the official Highcharts angular wrapper from https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular and have got a test chart working in my Angular 6 project.

The problem I'm having is trying to get the chart to only show once I have retrieved my data from an api.

This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="!loading">
        <highcharts-chart 
        [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    ></highcharts-chart>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is my component

```
loading = true;
Highcharts: any;
chartOptions: any;


public constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getClaimProviderCountsByMonth()
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                // this.chartOptions.series = [{
                //     data: data
                // }];
                this.Highcharts = Highcharts;
                this.chartOptions = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Stacked column chart'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
                    },
                    series: data.data
                };
                this.loading = false;
            },
            () => { });

}
```

However I get the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined"

My API data is formatted properly, and if I hard code it in it works ok, but I'm obviously running into async issues.

Comment: This should be `<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="loading && chartOptions">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are loading the Chart data from API asynchronously, you need to either use *ngIf or safe navigation operator to check the chartOptions as follows,

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="!loading && chartOptions">
```